# Can the "How to Ask" Sidebar be edited?

Tags: feature-request, sidebar

When you ask a question on any SE site, you get a sidebar like this one:

[image: How to Ask]

Who is allowed to edit this text for each community? This is visible to anyone who asks a question, even if they have ignored the FAQ and the About page, and is a very useful tool to getting direct advice across.

I can't find anything else on Meta about this beyond [this blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/asking-better-questions/) which just redirects new users to a different page when they ask, rather than allowing that sidebar text to be customized.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only developers can edit that text. That part of the site is not community-driven.

It's there for a good reason: to point people to resources on how to ask questions. Like you say, it's a very useful tool. However, it is probably fine in its current state.

If you would like to suggest an edit, post here on Meta with a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request), and see what response you get.

Comment: It isn't for MSO, but rather for [the Workplace](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/). In that case, should I be asking it here as well, or should I ask over in the Workplace Meta, and then relay whatever is decided over there to a feature-request here? Or what?

Comment: @jmac I'd suggest posting on Meta.Workplace, since that's the relevant audience. People on Meta.SO won't be able to give much feedback.

Comment: But nobody on Meta.Workplace is a developer (to the best of my knowledge). If we do decide on wording, what is the process to get a developer to change the actual sidebar? Perhaps I should rephrase my request as, "Allow people to edit the sidebar contents with their site without having to get a developer involved"?

Comment: @jmac If the request gets enough attention and is accepted by moderators, then community managers will pick up on it. Trust me, if it gets noticed, and is accepted, then it will be done.